# Write HTML form info included in php, in a CSV file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, csv

I am working on a small Wordpress plugin for my own purpose.

The first step is simple but there is something I don't understand about writing the data of the form inside a CSV file, using PHP.
I am using the readfile() to import the html code inside the PHP file.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/09/how-to-store-form-data-in-csv-file-using-php.html) but I don't understand why it doesn't work. No data is written in the CSV file.
Might it be because of the readfile()?

EDIT: Could it be because I didn't call my functions with a Wordpress Hook? Which one can be used at the moment the form is sent?

HTML code:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
    <input class="main-content__form--input" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" id="prenom" type="text" name="prenom" required>

    <label for="nom">Nom</label>
    <input class="main-content__form--input" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" id="nom" type="text" name="nom" required>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="main-content__form--input" id="email" type="email" name="email" required>

    <fieldset class="main-content__form--checkbox">
        <legend class="main-content__form--legend">Sélection des films</legend>

        <input type="checkbox" id="laHaine" name="films" value="La Haine">
        <label for="laHaine">La Haine</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="odyssee" name="films" value="l'Odyssée de l'espace">
        <label for="odyssee">l'Odyssée de l'espace</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="requiem" name="films" value="Requiem for a dream">
        <label for="requiem">Requiem for a dream</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="mulholland" name="films" value="Mulholland Drive">
        <label for="mulholland">Mulholland Drive</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="Carnage" name="films" value="Carnage">
        <label for="Carnage">Carnage</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="under" name="films" value="Under the skin">
        <label for="under">Under the skin</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="edward" name="films" value="Edward aux mains d'argent">
        <label for="edward">Edward aux mains d'argent</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="lost" name="films" value="Lost in translation">
        <label for="lost">Lost in translation</label>
    </fieldset>

    <input class="main-content__form--input" name="submit" type="submit" value="S'inscrire">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$error = '';
$fname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['prenom']);
$lname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['nom']);
$email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
$checkbox = $_POST['films'];
$error = '';


function clean_text($clean) {
    $clean = trim($clean);
    $clean = stripslashes($clean);
    $clean = htmlspecialchars($clean);
    return $clean;
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['prenom']) OR empty($_POST['nom']) OR empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error = '<p>Veuillez réessayer</p>';
        } else {
        $fname = clean_text($_POST['prenom']);
        $lname = clean_text($_POST['nom']);
        $email = clean_text($_POST['email']);
        }

        if($error = '') {
            $file_open = fopen('../form-to-csv.csv', 'a');
            $no_rows = count(file('form-to-csv.csv')); 
            if ($no_rows > 1) {
                $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) +1;
            } 
            $form_data = array(
            'id' => $no_rows,
            'prenom' => $fname,
            'nom' => $lname,
            'email' => $email,
            'films' => $checkbox
        );
            fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
            $error = '<p>Votre inscription a bien été prise en compte</p>';
            $fname = '';
            $lname = '';
            $email = '';
            $checkbox = '';
        }             
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about your code?  What specifically is happening and how is it failing?

Comment: Doubt if it's the problem but - you `fopen()` `'../form-to-csv.csv'` but count the lines from `'form-to-csv.csv'` which will be two different files.  Also not sure of the purpose of `$no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) +1;`

Comment: @David No info is written in the csv file.
I am new to PHP (use more JS) and don't know how to debug it). Sorry.

Comment: @NigelRen I don't understand about the lines.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in the comparison operator: `if($error = '') {` should be `if($error == '') {`.

**Edit:** It could be your file permissions especially edit. Change the permissions or try placing the csv file on your desktop: `$file_open = fopen('C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\form-to-csv.csv', 'a');`

**Edit 2:** Yes it is the file permissions. I executed your code with the comparison operator fixed, and it appended to the file successfully.

Comment: @Danier Visser Thanks, I corrected it but it still doesn't work. No info written in the CSV file.

Comment: @Danier Visser, That was the problem. I can't get rid of 'read only' for the plugin folder of Wordpress. I put the CSV file on the desktop. Thanks.